# Best settings for a daytime timelapse

Tags: timelapse, camera-settings

Soon I will to try out my first time lapse session with a dolly that I built, for that reason I would like to ask to anyone that already did timelapse photography what are the best settings that you used:

- Time interval between each shot
- Step/distance between each shot
- output video fps

I only thought of these 3 settings, but if you think there are others that should be taken into consideration please do tell me.

Comment: This is so vague I'm afraid there is no one answer. It is like asking what exposure parameters of a daytime image. How would one ever know! I suggest you try some test shots before the sequence.

Comment: Thanks @mattdm, I looked for a while I thought that it was pretty strange that there wasn't any question like this already.

Comment: So does mattdm's link help?  If it covers much of your question, you might want to alter your question to ask about anything specifics the other topic doesn't cover

Comment: @MikeW there is nothing else I will delete this question in 2 days.

Comment: No need to delete, if someone searches for daytime timelapse they may find this and can follow the link to the other question.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, I did a time lapse of some work in my garden, I set it to aperture priority of f8 (nice wide angle) to get as much as possible in focus and when for a 15 minute interval.

Video time lapse I Google's Picasa, which I can't find online !  soon as I can, I'll post it.